# Describe EBS details volume with AWSCLI

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I need to list all owner's aws ami and any details about it.

The following line returns the image_id, CreationDate, Name and organized by CreationDate:

**aws ec2 describe-images --owners  --query 'Images[*].[ImageId, CreationDate, Name]'  | sort_by(@, &[1])' --output text**

But, i need any information about BlockDevicesMapping like an Ebs volume [snapshot id, Volume size e etc...]

I did the following line aws ec2 describe-images --owners  --query 'Images[*].[ImageId, CreationDate, Name, BlockDeviceMappings:[Ebs:{SnapshotID}]] --output text. But, the search on terminal stopped.

I tried a lot of ways.

Thank's for help-me.

Answer (score 0):

The output from describe-images is as follows.

```
{
    "Images": [
        {
            "VirtualizationType": "hvm",
            "Description": "Provided by Red Hat, Inc.",
            "PlatformDetails": "Red Hat Enterprise Linux",
            "EnaSupport": true,
            "Hypervisor": "xen",
            "State": "available",
            "SriovNetSupport": "simple",
            "ImageId": "ami-1234567890EXAMPLE",
            "UsageOperation": "RunInstances:0010",
            "BlockDeviceMappings": [
                {
                    "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
                    "Ebs": {
                        "SnapshotId": "snap-111222333444aaabb",
                        "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                        "VolumeType": "gp2",
                        "VolumeSize": 10,
                        "Encrypted": false
                    }
                }
            ],
            "Architecture": "x86_64",
            "ImageLocation": "123456789012/RHEL-8.0.0_HVM-20190618-x86_64-1-Hourly2-GP2",
            "RootDeviceType": "ebs",
            "OwnerId": "123456789012",
            "RootDeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
            "CreationDate": "2019-05-10T13:17:12.000Z",
            "Public": true,
            "ImageType": "machine",
            "Name": "RHEL-8.0.0_HVM-20190618-x86_64-1-Hourly2-GP2"
        }
    ]
}
```

As you see, BlockDeviceMappings is an array, so you should flatten it first before you attempt to access its objects.

I would suggest specifying `--owners 12347989`. If you attempt to get all amis of all owners, terminal will hang. I ran the below command with my accountId and got the desired output, but if I don't specify owner, my terminal just hangs.

Try this:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --owners amazon --query 'Images[*].[ImageId, CreationDate, Name, BlockDeviceMappings[0].DeviceName, BlockDeviceMapping[0].VolumeSize, BlockDeviceMappings[0].SnapshotId]' --output text
```

Comment: This command work partialy, but firt step is done. This one show me the results, but, VolumeSize and SnapshotId returns "None". I Keep your information about array and tried change some elements. It doesn't work fully.

Comment: Can you pick an ami id and see if that particular ami has ebs volume size and snapshotId?
For example:  If ami is backed my instance store volume, it wouldn't have ebs object

Comment: I changed array's index and returns the values: aws ec2 describe-images --owners <OWNER ID> --query 'Images[*].[ImageId, CreationDate, Name, BlockDeviceMappings[0].DeviceName, BlockDeviceMappings[0].Ebs.SnapshotId, BlockDeviceMappings[1].Ebs.SnapshotId, BlockDeviceMappings[2].Ebs.SnapshotId]' --output table. It's Working. Thank so much!  @Mahesh